# Trouble with vertical lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, stix, tikzlibrary

I've a trouble because I'd like to create two vertical lines for generate a determinant of a 3-by-3 matrix. I have tried with scope-environment, but the result is an error. How can I do? This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{stix}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.center)]
  \tikzset{BarreStyle/.style =   {opacity=.4,line width=4 mm,line cap=round,color=#1}}
    \tikzset{SignePlus/.style =   {above left,inner sep=1.5pt,opacity=.4,circle,fill=#1}}
    \tikzset{SigneMoins/.style =   {below left,inner sep=-0.5pt,opacity=.4,circle,fill=#1}}
    \tikzset{PlusProduct/.style={anchor=north west,rectangle,rounded corners=5pt,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=2.5pt,opacity=.4,fill=#1}}
    \tikzset{MoinsProduct/.style={anchor=south west,rectangle,rounded corners=5pt,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=2.5pt,opacity=.4,fill=#1}}
% the matrices
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes = {node style ge},,column sep=0 mm] 
{ a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}  \\
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
};

\begin{scope} % From here to ...
\draw (1-|1) -- (1-|3);
\draw (3-|1) -- (3-|3);
\end{scope} % ... here, Overleaf gives me error, ... why? 
\draw [BarreStyle=blue] (A-1-1.north west) node[SignePlus=blue] {$+$} to (A-3-3.south east) node[PlusProduct=blue]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{33}$};
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue] (A-2-1.north west) node[SignePlus=blue] {$+$} to (A-4-3.south east)  node[PlusProduct=blue]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{13}$};
 \draw [BarreStyle=blue] (A-3-1.north west) node[SignePlus=blue] {$+$} to (A-5-3.south east)  node[PlusProduct=blue]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{23}$};
 
 \draw [BarreStyle=red]  (A-3-1.south west) node[SigneMoins=red] {\strut $-$} to (A-1-3.north east) node[MoinsProduct=red]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{13}$};
 \draw [BarreStyle=red]  (A-4-1.south west) node[SigneMoins=red] {\strut $-$} to (A-2-3.north east) node[MoinsProduct=red]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{23}$};
 \draw [BarreStyle=red]  (A-5-1.south west) node[SigneMoins=red] {\strut $-$} to (A-3-3.north east) node[MoinsProduct=red]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{33}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much in advanced

Comment: If you remove `nodes = {node style ge}` (undefined ) and `\draw (1-|1) -- (1-|3); \draw (3-|1) -- (3-|3);` it works fine. If you can add definition for ge and nodes names 1 and 3, do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, that you like to ad left and right delimiters to matrix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath}
%\usepackage{stix}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.center)]
\tikzset{Barr/.style = {opacity=.4,line width=4 mm,line cap=round,color=#1},
         Sigp/.style = {circle,  minimum size=4mm, left,inner sep=0pt,opacity=.4,fill=blue,
                        node contents={$+$}},
         Sigm/.style = {Sigp,fill=red, node contents={\vphantom{+}$-$}},
         Prod/.style = {rounded corners=5pt,
                        inner sep=2pt,opacity=.4,fill=#1, right},
         }
% the matrices
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, 
             %nodes = {node style ge},
             column sep=1ex,
             row sep=1ex
             ]
{ a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}  \\
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
};
\draw[semithick]    (A-1-1.north west) -- (A-3-1.south west)
                    (A-1-3.north east) -- (A-3-3.south east);
\draw [Barr=blue] (A-1-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-3-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{33}$};
\draw [Barr=blue] (A-2-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-4-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{13}$};
\draw [Barr=blue] (A-3-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-5-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{23}$};

\draw [Barr=red]  (A-3-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-1-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{13}$};
\draw [Barr=red]  (A-4-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-2-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{23}$};
\draw [Barr=red]  (A-5-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-3-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{33}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(I took a liberty and a little wee change your  images's design)

**Edit:**
Ah, last two rows on your image are extension of matrix (my shame). Now (hopefully) image is correct):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath}
%\usepackage{stix}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.center)]
\tikzset{Barr/.style = {opacity=.4,line width=4 mm,line cap=round,color=#1},
         Sigp/.style = {circle,  fill=blue, fill opacity=0.4, text opacity=1,
                        minimum size=4mm, left, inner sep=0pt,
                        node contents={$+$}},
         Sigm/.style = {Sigp,fill=red, node contents={\vphantom{+}$-$}},
         Prod/.style = {rounded corners=5pt,
                        fill=#1,  fill opacity=0.4, text opacity=1, inner sep=2pt, right},
         }
% the matrices
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,
             column sep=1ex,
             row sep=1ex
             ]
{ a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}  \\
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
};
\draw[semithick]    (A-1-1.north west) -- (A-3-1.south west)
                    (A-1-3.north east) -- (A-3-3.south east);
\draw [Barr=blue] (A-1-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-3-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{33}$}
                  (A-2-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-4-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{13}$}
                  (A-3-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-5-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{23}$};

\draw [Barr=red]  (A-3-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-1-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{13}$}
                  (A-4-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-2-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{23}$}
                  (A-5-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-3-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{33}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you. If I wanted that `left-and-right-delimiter=|` are resized from `a_{11}` to `a_{31}` and from `a_{13}` to `a_{33}`, how could I do? Please, thanks.

Comment: @Puck, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Puck, you cane express your thankfulness by up-vote my answer and even accept it by stoke on up-triangle and check mark at top left side of answer. By this you will inform other user that your problem is solved. BTW,  as far as I see, so far you not accept  any of received answers. Are no one of the solve your problem(s) and you still wait on solutions ?

Comment: Already accepted! Thank you so much, again!

Comment: How can I add a `\hdashline` in a `tizkpicture`?